# How did we get $W_g=W_b$ from $\dfrac{U'(W_g)}{U'(W_b)}=1$?

Tags: risk

My question is from Nicholson-Snyder's text , E-book [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww-bcf.usc.edu%2F~ebayrak%2Fteaching%2F500F12%2FXYZ.pdf&ei=qQK3Uq_WIMumrQfUgoH4AQ&usg=AFQjCNES-AhfZS7ktOPZ1tSLvjC4PxqHhw&sig2=FkPz3kF5gQjDDMcYDeTApQ&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bmk).

My question is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJmyi.png), from page 217 of the book. (I can't post image as my reputation is not enough.)

How did we get $W_g=W_b$ from $\dfrac{U'(W_g)}{U'(W_b)}=1$ ?

Comment: @ honso : maybe from the injectivity of $U'$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$U$ is usually strictly concave. So $U'$ is strictly decreasing and is therefore injective.

Comment: OK, but it is not assumed ! and we are perhaps going to prove risk aversion, another name of concave utility, isn't it?

Comment: @honso: It is assumed. See the footnote on page 216 before the proposition in question. It is bad that the book put such important assumption in an obscure footnote. Also the concavity is needed for proving the sufficiency and uniqueness of the concluding price being truly utility maximizing. The book is somewhat mathematically deficient.

Comment: If U'>0 then U is increasing not decreasing.

Comment: @Nic: Yes, you are right but it does not contradict what I said. I said $U'$ (not $U$) is strictly decreasing.

Comment: @Hansen, I am the same user and can't log in and can't accept yours! Please pardon me! I AM TRYING MY BEST AND HAVE ALSO ASKED FOR HELP AT META.STACKOVERFLOW

Comment: @honso: No worries. You may want to try using Gmail or Facebook to log in.